# Player controls not responding to clicks

Tags: html, user-interface, video.js

**Ive been trying to** 
**embed a video unsing Video-Js** ([videojs.com](http://videojs.com))with **flash fallback**
and after some fiddeling around i got the **controls** to show up correctly 
(they were messed up before) tho **non-functional**.

I've read through parts documentation alredy but i 
**can't even track down the problem** completely.

The weird thing is that they do respond to mousover events, so there can't be any invisible element above them.

---

This is a JsFiddle containing all the js/css/html im using right now:
[Open in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minzkraut/cmLm9r0x/7/)

```html
Sorry, the snippet is too big for SO<br>
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/minzkraut/cmLm9r0x/7/">Open JsFiddle </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely follow what you were trying to do, but it looks like you've taken the html of a rendered video.js player and inserted some flash object. Copying the rendered player html doesn't work - the control elements don't have any of the event listeners that make them behave as video controls rather than just look like controls. video.js has it's own flash tech that it will load when needed.

You also have a very old version of video.js

All you need is this:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.js"></script>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="http://www.download.ieq-systems.de/4317/core/unsere_firma/video/freese_video.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
</video>
```